# SQL DB2 query using EXCEPT

Tags: sql, db2

The following is a query for "List customers who own items in all the available colours.
That is, for every available colour, the customer owns some
item in that colour."
Item is a table of items bought by customers

```
select cust#, cname
    from Customer
except
select C.cust#, C.cname
    from ( select D.cust#, A.colour
        from Customer D,
            Avail_Colours A
        except
        select I.cust#, I.colour
        from Item I
    ) as M,
    Customer C
where C.cust# = M.cust#;
```

What if I wanted to rephrase the question to: "List customers who own all items in some available color" That is, list available colours and customers where a customer owns all items in that colour?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have access to DB2, so I could not test it.  Please kindly consider it just an idea and not as a ready to use solution. I used standard SQL.

```
SELECT c.cust#, MAX(c.cname), a.colour 
FROM Customer c 
JOIN Items i ON c.cust# = i.cust#
JOIN Avail_Colors a ON a.colour=i.colour
GROUP BY c.cust#, i.colour
HAVING COUNT(*)=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Item WHERE i.colour = a.colour) 
ORDER BY c.cust#
```

Answer (score 0):

The following version makes the assumption that the colours are all available:

```
select i.cust#, i.colour, COUNT(distinct i.item#) as numItems
from items i join
     (select i.cust# , COUNT(distinct i.item#) as numItems
      from items i
      group by i.cust#
     ) isum
     on isum.cust# = i.cust#
group by i.cust#, i.colour
having i.numItems = max(isum.numItems)
```

It returns the customer number and colour that is present  for all items, if any.

To get available colors, you can just add  the following `where` clause to the subquery and outer query:

```
where colour in (select colour from Avail_Colours)
```

Answer (score 0):

*(The following assumes that you are looking for a solution using EXCEPT.)*

Take the cross product of all available items with all available customers and all available colours. Now take away from that set all the existing items, with their actual owners and colours. Apparently, if a customer has all items in some colour, the resulting set will lack the corresponding colour(s) for that customer. You can get the list of all such customers and their "full-set" colours if you take away this resulting set from the cross product of all customers and colours.

Translating the above into EXCEPT SQL, here's what you can get:

```
SELECT D.cust#,
       D.name,
       C.colour
FROM   Customer D,
       Avail_Colours C
EXCEPT
SELECT D.cust#,
       D.name,
       S.colour
FROM   (
        SELECT D.cust#,
               I.item#,
               C.colour
        FROM   Items I,
               Customer D,
               Avail_Colours C
        EXCEPT
        SELECT I.cust#,
               I.item#,
               I.colour
        FROM   Items I
       ) S
JOIN   Customer D
ON     D.cust# = S.cust#
;
```